# Which is the best charset to pass data to php?

Tags: java, php, arrays, string, byte

In my Java App, I want to pass individual bytes of information to a php script via POST. In order to do that, I convert the byte[] into a String.
Now, which charset is best for this operation? I want to keep the amount of data transmitted as tiny as possible.
Right now, I'm using ISO-8859-1, but i was worried, as it contains '?' and '=', whicht I thought, might make php interpret the data wrong...

Comment: Perform url encoding, so those characters won't cause any problem.

Comment: This would expand the url in a way, that I could pass around Hexadecimal values just as well... Seems like I have no other choice.

Comment: Is there a charset, that only contains url-compatible characters?

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out using Base64 encoding is probably the best way to achieve this ^^

I used [this class](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/Base64encoderdecoder.htm), and moddet it to use  _ - ~ as special characters, instead of  / = +